# Unable to marshal IMAPMessage in Android

Tags: android, jakarta-mail, marshalling, unmarshalling

I am newbie to android. Can anyone please tell the procedure to marshal IMAPMessage in android in order to pass Messages between activities?

Comment: Let `IMAPMessage` class to implement [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)...

Comment: How to do that? I am newbie therefore sorry for the naive query

Comment: ask the Google like `implementing parcelable android`...